# Chaining max with . operator in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use the `.` operator to write a function that takes three values and returns their maximum.

Obviously, the following work

```
max3 a b c = max a (max b c)
max3 a b c = max a $ max b c
```

but I would like to use `.`. I tried

```
max3 a b c = max a . max b c
```

but get the error

```
Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> Float' with actual type `Float'
In the first argument of `max', namely `b'
```

I know that the example is silly, but a nice explanation of the correct way to do this *and why* would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One must remember that `(.)` isn't some built-in magic operator; it's a normal function defined as any other function would be.

Comment: @AJFarmar The issue (although I did not realize at the time of asking) was primarily that the error message was not helpful. I still don't understand why max should expect `a0 -> Float`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall the definition of `(.)`:

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

You have the expression

```
max a (max b c)
```

which matches the right hand side of `(f . g) x` if we set `f = max a`, `g = max b`, and `x = c`. Using these substitutions on the left-hand side of the definition of `(.)`, we get:

```
(max a . max b) c = max a (max b c)
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's introduce some more parentheses in your first example:

```
max3 a b c = (max a) ((max b) c)
```

Now compare that to the ones in your last one:

```
max3 a b c = (max a) . ((max b) c)
```

Or, if we write `(.)` in prefix notation:

```
max3 a b c = (.) (max a) ((max b) c)
```

And now we see why you get that error. In order to type-check, `(max b) c` needs to be a function:

```
(.)       :: (b     -> c    )  -> (a -> b   ) -> a -> c
max a     ::  Float -> Float
max b c   ::                           Float
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

We get a better error message if we use a constrained version of `max` instead:

```
maxFloat :: Float -> Float -> Float
maxFloat = max

max3 a b c = max a . max b c
```

Now the error message is a lot better:

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type ‘a0 -> Float’ with actual type ‘Float’
> Possible cause: ‘maxFloat’ is applied to too many arguments
> In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘maxFloat b c’
> In the expression: maxFloat a . maxFloat b c
> ```

That being said, let's actually tackle the problem:

```
max3 a b c = max a ((max b) c)
           = (max a . max b) c
```

Note that you can also write

```
max3 :: Ord a => a -> a -> a -> a   
max3 a b = max a . max b
```